# Vue CLI and Yarn workspaces

Tags: vue.js, yarnpkg, vue-cli, lerna, yarn-workspaces

Is it possible to use the Vue CLI—particularly its plugins—within a multi-package Lerna and Yarn workspace repository? I'd love to be able install the Jest plugin and have it be available to all of my packages.

For example, here's my root `package.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": ["packages/*"],
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "test": "yarn workspaces run test"
  },
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.3.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.3.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^4.3.1",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.3.1",
    ... other dependencies installed by Vue CLI
  }
}
```

and then package's `package.json`:

```
{
  ...,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

If I run `yarn test` in the root of my project, I get the following error:

```
$ yarn workspaces run test
> my-package
$ vue-cli-service test:unit
ERROR command "test:unit" does not exist.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Is there something I'm missing? Or is this just not supported by the Vue CLI?